# Is there any way to improve EF Core performance?

Tags: performance, linq, entity-framework-core, blazor-webassembly

```
List<tablename> results = new List<tablename>();

if (viewModel.CSku != null )
{
    results = _context.tablename
                      .Where(x => x.CSku == viewModel.CSku)
                      .AsNoTracking().ToList();

    if (viewModel.CDesc != null)
        results = results.Where(x => x.CDesc.Contains(viewModel.CDesc.ToUpper())).ToList();

    if (viewModel.WCode != null)
        results = results.Where(x => x.WCode.Contains(viewModel.WCode.ToUpper())).ToList();

    return _mapper.Map<IEnumerable<tablenameViewModel>>(results).ToList();
}

if (viewModel.Length == null && viewModel.Pattern == null && 
    viewModel.Length == null && viewModel.Prefix == null && 
    viewModel.Species == null)
{
    var x = _context.tablename.AsNoTracking().ToList();

    if (viewModel.WCode != null)
        x = x.Where(x => x.WCode.Contains(viewModel.WCode.ToUpper())).ToList();
        return _mapper.Map<IEnumerable<tablenameViewModel>>(x) ;
}
else
{
    results = _context.tablename.AsNoTracking().ToList();

    if (viewModel.Length != null)
        results = results.Where(x => x.Length.Trim() == viewModel.Length.Trim()).ToList();

    if (viewModel.Species != null)
        results = results.Where(x => x.Species.Trim() == viewModel.Species.Trim()).ToList();

    if (viewModel.Pattern != null)
        results = results.Where(x => x.Pattern.Trim() == viewModel.Pattern.Trim()).ToList();

    if (viewModel.Prefix != null)
        results = results.Where(x => x.Prefix.Trim() == viewModel.Prefix.Trim()).ToList();

    if (viewModel.WCode != null)
        results = results.Where(x => x.WCode.Contains(viewModel.WCode.ToUpper())).ToList();

    return _mapper.Map<IEnumerable<tablenameViewModel>>(results);
}
```

The above code is taking 2 minutes to load even with the filter conditions. I tried with `.AsNoTracking()`, but it still is taking the same time to load.

Is there any way to modify the code and improve the performance of the page?

Answer (score 3):

You need to build the query dynamically. `results = _context.tablename.AsNoTracking().ToList();` Will fetch all rows from the table into memory which can be very slow for obvious reasons. For starters you can do:

```cs
if (viewModel.CSku != null )
{
    var query = _context.tablename
         .Where(x => x.CSku == viewModel.CSku)
         .AsNoTracking();

    if (viewModel.CDesc != null)
        query = query.Where(x => x.CDesc.Contains(viewModel.CDesc.ToUpper()));

    if (viewModel.WCode != null)
        query = query.Where(x => x.WCode.Contains(viewModel.WCode.ToUpper()));

    return _mapper.Map<IEnumerable<tablenameViewModel>>(query.AsEnumerable()).ToList();
}
```

And then use the similar approach for other cases.

Note that AutoMapper has [queryable extensions](https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Queryable-Extensions.html) which can allow using `ProjectTo` in some cases (not all mappings can be translated into SQL), i.e.:

```cs
return query
    .ProjectTo<tablenameViewModel>(_mapper.ConfigurationProvider)
    .ToList();
```

This has advantage that only needed columns will be queried.